# Product of group indexed by topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For a topological space $X$, what does $(S^1)^X$ stand for? I'm thinking it is the product of $X$ copies of $S^1$? In this way this set is just all the maps $X
 \rightarrow S^1$.

I'm reading a text which refer to this one as a group (I guess the group structure is pointwise multiplication?), and it continues to explain that

> This group is the product of discrete group $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ with
> the component of identity, which is the group of all maps $X
>  \rightarrow S^1$, which are homotopically trivial

How can I see this? I think the above statement is equivalent of saying that the different components of $(S^1)^X$ is in 1-1 correspondence with elements of $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$. How to see this action is transitive and free?

Comment: For $X^Y$, we usually mean the topological space whose points are continuous maps $Y\to X$ and the topology is the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).  In general, see [exponential law for spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces).

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Anyway, the easiest way to explain why it is $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ (assuming $X$ at least has homotopy type of a CW complex) is to look at Čech cohomology.  Are you comfortable with Čech cohomology theory?

Comment: @user10354138 I know some so I think it works for me. Anyway thanks in advance!!

Comment: So take an open cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i:i\in i\}$ of $X$.  On each $U_i$, if $U_i$ is e.g. contractible, we can lift $f$ to $f_i\colon U_i\to\mathbb{R}$.  Then define $f_{ij}$ on $U_{ij}=U_i\cap U_j$ by $f_i-f_j$.  Clearly $(f_{ij}\colon U_{ij}\to\mathbb{Z})_{i,j\in I}$ satisfies cocycle condition, so is a 1-cocycle.  Being a 1-coboundary means there is a 0-cochain $(h_i\colon U_i\to\mathbb{Z})_{i\in I}$ with $f_{ij}=h_i-h_j$ so $f_i-h_i$ patches together to give you $X\to\mathbb{R}$ which you can homotope to constant.  So you get $\check{H}^1(\mathcal{U};\mathbb{Z})$ being the obstruction.

Comment: Anyway, it is well-known that if $X$ is "nice enough" (path-connected paracompact Hausdorff probably would do), then $[X,K(G,n)]\cong\check{H}^n(X;G)$.  In particular, since $S^1=K(\mathbb{Z},1)$, we have $[X,S^1]\cong\check{H}^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @user10354138 I got the idea!! Thank you.